# Как проверить большое целое число на четность или нечетность?

Tags: c#

Написал программку, которая считывает с **textbox** число и проверяет его на четность и не четность. 
Программа работает, все норм, НО, выскакивает ошибка, когда в **textbox** вводишь слишком большое число, например: 1111111111111111111111111.
Ругается на данную строчку кода:

```
int a = int.Parse("0" + textBox1.Text);
```

> System.OverflowException: "Значение было недопустимо малым или недопустимо большим для Int32."

Я понимаю, почему такая ошибка. Но не понимаю, как ее можно обыграть, чтоб любое целое число, которое я ввожу в **textbox** , проверялось на четность или нечетность.

Comment: Поставить [тип](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/int) принимающий значение больше, либо ограничивайте ввод в textBox.

Comment: Правильно я понял, что, в моем случае это long?

Comment: А это уже вам решать. Я не знаю какого размера ваши числа. Если в `long` умещаются, то да.

Comment: У меня как раз задача в том, точнее я ее себе сам поставил, что в textbox можно будет ввести любое число, пусть там например будет 1 и куча нулей. Вот именно такой момент, как обыграть?

Comment: [BigInteger](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете сделать так:

```
string pole = textBox1.Text;
if((int.Parse("0" +pole[pole.Length-1])%2)==0)
{
///четное
}else{
///нечетное
}
```

В итоге, вы проверяете только последний символ.

Comment: а зачем ведущий ноль добавлять?

Comment: Аналог `.Tostring()`, для `Parse` строка должна быть явно конвертирована в string

Answer (score 15):

Для того, чтобы проверить введенное число на четность, совсем необязательно конвертировать его в `int`. Можно просто проверить последний введенный символ. Если это цифра 0, 2, 4, 6, или 8, то число четное. Если цифра 1, 3, 5, 7, или 9, то число нечетное. Если другой символ, то ошибка.

Comment: Идея хорошая, надо будет попробовать, но я пока учусь)). И в данном случае у меня вот возникла такая проблема, и я хочу попытаться ее исправить. В процессе написания были проблемы и я их сам все исправил. Но тут мне понадобилась помощь)

Comment: блин, какое элегантное решение.... А я затупил и подумал сначала предложить bigint или задать максимальное количество для ввода в сам текстбокс. Но твое решение реально лучше) Молодец

Comment: всё равно придётся немножко ограничить пользователя в вариантах ввода (только цифры), иначе он может ввести целое число с нулевой/пустой дробной частью, например **123,0**, или в экспоненциальном формате.